# Silverlight combobox number of items shown refresh

Tags: silverlight, combobox, silverlight-2.0

I have two combo boxes on a SL page. When Combo 1 updates, a service is called and populates Combo 2.

On the first call, 3 results are returned. When the combo box is expanded, you can see all 3 options.

On the second call, 4 results are returned. When the combo box is expanded, you can see 3 options, with a vertical scroll bar.

If I reload and do those steps in reverse, I get 4 rows the first call and 3 rows + a blank row on the second call. (No, the blank is not a record. It cannot be selected.)

It appears that the drop down list size keeps the first generated height.

How can I refresh the combo box max items shown after each service call?

Thanks!

**Edit #1**

The code follows the M-V-VM pattern. When the page loads, the `Group1` populates the first combo box, and nothing is selected. When the user makes a selection, that selection is bound to Group1Selection.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Group1}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Group1Selection}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Group2}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Group2Selection}" />
```

In the viewmodel, in the set accessor of the `Group1Selection` property, I have something like

```
set
{
    if (group1Selection != value)
    {
        group1Selection = value;
        PopulateGroup2();
        OnPropertyChanged("Group1Selection");
    }
}
```

Where PopulateGroup2 performs my service call async, gets the data, and puts that data into the exposed property of `Group2`.

Under "normal" conditions, this isn't a problem, since most options have dozens of possible selections. However, a couple of the `Group1` choices only have 3 or 4 child choices. If one of those is selected first, then the height of the ComboBox, for the rest of that application instance is set to 3 or 4, respectively, instead of maxing out at 8 shown items.

Following the M-V-VM pattern, there is no code in the code-behind.

Comment: Are you using data binding in your combo box 2 ItemsSource?  What does the XAML look like?

Comment: If you are not using data binding, what does the code look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in the ComboBox in Silverlight 2. I think its been fixed in SL 3.

You can fix this by doing the following:

1. Inherit from the ComboBox

   public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
2. Get a reference to the "Popup" part of the ComboBox inside the OnApplyTemplate() method

   ```
       Popup thePopup = GetTemplateChild("Popup") as Popup;
       FrameworkElement thePopupContent = thePopup.Child as FrameworkElement;
   ```
3. Override the OnItemsChanged method
4. Inside the overridden OnItemsChagned method reset the Height & Width dependency properties on the Popup using the ClearValue(DP) method.

   ```
           thePopupContent.ClearValue(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty);
           thePopupContent.ClearValue(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty);
   ```

You can clear the Max and Min Height & Width properties if you are worried about those too.

Comment: Total pain - but much better than the alternative of destroying the combobox and adding a new one to the children.

Comment: This is the best solution to this issue that I've seen. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree...but you gotta do what you gotta do :o)

SL2, I love you, but I can't wait for SL3 to RTM!

Comment: You can also just obtain PopupBorder (which is the Popup's child) directly. Still a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

That was a perfect solution. Thank you markti.

For those interested the class would look like this:

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives; 

public class WorkAroundComboBox: ComboBox
{
    FrameworkElement thePopupContent;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        Popup thePopup = GetTemplateChild("Popup") as Popup;
        thePopupContent = thePopup.Child as FrameworkElement;
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    protected override void OnItemsChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        thePopupContent.ClearValue(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty);
        thePopupContent.ClearValue(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty);
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that Silverlight doesn't fully realize that the data behind ComboBox 2 has changed. Maybe try adding `OnPropertyChanged("Group2")` to the set for `Group1` - that should help Silverlight to realize that it needs to update the bindings for ComboBox 2.

It also might help to call `OnPropertyChanged` for `Group2Selection`, since the previous value is no longer valid.